# Why does a @Size validation annotation influence DataNucleus JPA database schema?

Tags: java, validation, jpa, datanucleus

A valid entity which uses both JPA and validation annotations like

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final int IMAGE_COUNT_MAX = 5;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Size(max = IMAGE_COUNT_MAX, message = "Maximal " + IMAGE_COUNT_MAX + " images are allowed")
    @Basic
    @Lob
    private ArrayList<byte[]> imageData = new ArrayList<>();
```

causes the `max` value of `@Size` to be passed as length attribute of the `LONG VARCHAR FOR BIT DATA` which is invalid SQL in Apache Derby and thus results in

```
SEVERE: Error thrown executing CREATE TABLE MYENTITY
(
    ID BIGINT NOT NULL generated always as identity (start with 1),
    IMAGEDATA LONG VARCHAR FOR BIT DATA(5)
) : Syntax error: Encountered "(" at line 4, column 40.
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "(" at line 4, column 40.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.datasource.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:291)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.datasource.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:291)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.table.AbstractTable.executeDdlStatement(AbstractTable.java:849)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.table.AbstractTable.executeDdlStatementList(AbstractTable.java:800)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.table.AbstractTable.create(AbstractTable.java:522)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.table.AbstractTable.exists(AbstractTable.java:580)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager$ClassAdder.performTablesValidation(RDBMSStoreManager.java:3447)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager$ClassAdder.run(RDBMSStoreManager.java:2969)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.AbstractSchemaTransaction.execute(AbstractSchemaTransaction.java:118)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.manageClasses(RDBMSStoreManager.java:1672)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.getDatastoreClass(RDBMSStoreManager.java:648)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSPersistenceHandler.getDatastoreClass(RDBMSPersistenceHandler.java:88)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSPersistenceHandler.insertObject(RDBMSPersistenceHandler.java:123)
    at org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerImpl.internalMakePersistent(StateManagerImpl.java:4535)
    at org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerImpl.flush(StateManagerImpl.java:5735)
    at org.datanucleus.flush.FlushOrdered.execute(FlushOrdered.java:106)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.flushInternal(ExecutionContextImpl.java:4058)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.flush(ExecutionContextImpl.java:4004)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.flush(JPAEntityManager.java:946)
    at richtercloud.datanucleus.validation.schema.confusion.NewMain.main(NewMain.java:33)
Caused by: ERROR 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "(" at line 4, column 40.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ParserImpl.parseStatementOrSearchCondition(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ParserImpl.parseStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
    ... 22 more
```

Could this be a - hard to understand - feature in JPA or DataNucleus and - if yes - how can I map both the field in JPA and specify validation constraints (if possible without involving XML configuration files)? Or is this a bug in DataNucleus?

I'm using

```
richtercloud:datanucleus-validation-schema-confusion:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
+- org.datanucleus:javax.persistence:jar:2.2.0-release:compile
+- org.datanucleus:datanucleus-api-jpa:jar:5.1.4:compile
+- org.datanucleus:datanucleus-core:jar:5.1.4:compile
+- org.datanucleus:datanucleus-rdbms:jar:5.1.4:compile
+- org.apache.derby:derbyclient:jar:10.14.1.0:compile
+- org.apache.derby:derby:jar:10.14.1.0:compile
\- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.3.2.Final:compile
   +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile
   \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.CR2:compile
```

A `columnDefinition` in `@Column` is simply ignored. That shouldn't be the case, right?

I'm referring to and using DataNucleus JPA (as opposed to JDO).

An SSCCE can be found at https://gitlab.com/krichter/datanucleus-validation-schema-confusion.

Comment: It's supposed to be a feature. To quote the DataNucleus docs: 'A further use of the Bean Validation annotations @Size(max=...) and @NotNull is that if you specify these then you have no need to specify the equivalent JDO "length" and "allowsNull" attributes since they equate to the same thing' (see here: http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_1/jdo/bean_validation.html). Do you absolutely need to use DataNucleus?

Comment: I understand that your edit has to do with the fact that you think the above comment does not apply. Note that DataNucleus mimics JPA functionality using its JDO implementation, so most of the 'features' apply to JPA, as well. Here's the relevant doc for JPA: http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_1/jpa/bean_validation.html. JPA is really a second class citizen in DataNucleus, so be prepared for even more surprises

Comment: @crizzis Thank you for your input. How can I turn this "feature" off? Setting `javax.persistence.validation.mode` to `none` doesn't help because it seems to influence pre-persist validation and not the schema generation.

Comment: It might well not be possible. I can only suggest filing a bug report with DataNucleus (also, at the risk of sounding biased, let me repeat: do you absolutely need to use DataNucleus?)

Comment: @crizzis With a very simple project with 20 entities and about 15 relationships, I experienced 17 bugs of which I filed 7 of all 4 FLOSS JPA implementations in the last 8 weeks. They apparently all don't use unit tests (even those that are not reference implementations which often suffer from release a trash version on time and fix later). Afaik every professional project must use ObjectDB, but then I don't get why the others still exist...

Comment: @crizzis I reported this at https://github.com/datanucleus/datanucleus-rdbms/issues/246.

Comment: @crizzis, yes you sound biased, and NO datanucleus does NOT 'mimic' jpa using jdo handling, nor is that api a 'second class citizen'. There is no jdo handling required to use it for jpa, and hasnt been for years. Kindly stick to facts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be because DataNucleus supports processing javax.validation `@Size(max="...")` annotation as the equivalent of `@Column(length="...")`, as [their docs state](http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/persistence.html#bean_validation).

As for the reason behind your problem, that would require debugging.

The `@Size` should only be processed as their extension on a String-type field/property (what I've used it for), so maybe there is no check on that and it just applies it regardless of your field?

Maybe the JDBC driver doesn't report the particular JDBC/SQL type as not allowing a size? If that is the case then a bug report on the JDBC driver would be the way to go.

Also, while this feature makes a lot of sense to many people (I've used it), it would make sense for it to be configurable for those that want "strict JPA" schema handling (what you consider obvious and a main use-case isn't the same for all people, so any JPA provider is only as good as the requests it gets and the flexibility it provides). The nearest a cursory glance down the code gives https://github.com/datanucleus/datanucleus-core/blob/master/src/main/java/org/datanucleus/metadata/annotations/AnnotationManagerImpl.java#L101 as the place where it is enabled, so why not provide a way of turning it off?

Comment: It's just been fixed. The property controlling the evaluation of validation annotations is called `datanucleus.metadata.javaxValidationShortcuts` and defaults to false, see https://github.com/datanucleus/datanucleus-core/issues/278 for details.